# When told "The system reduces to one in row echelon form" what does this mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does this mean that in its reduced form it is an identity matrix? Or is it describing something different?

Comment: row echelon form means Gaussian elimination has operated on the rows

Comment: I was wondering more what the "reduces to one" part means specifically, apologies for not being clear. After the Elementary row operations have been performed, does it exhibit something in particular?

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible the word "one" is being used as a pronoun here. The statement would be: "The system reduces to a system in row echelon form."

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have all you need and more here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form